# Parsing an empty property into an empty Map with PureConfig

Tags: scala, hocon, pureconfig

I have a case class like the following:

```
case class MyConfig(arg1:String, extraArgs:Map[String,String])
```

and I would like the following to be parsable from the HOCON config

```
{
    arg1 = 'hello world'
}
```

However this fail because `extraArgs` is not defined. I could make `extraArgs` optional in my case class, but this would be redundant. Is there a way to instruct PureConfig to parse an absent field as an empty collection?

Comment: Does it work if you give it a default argument?

Comment: Yes although I am not a big fan of default arguments

Comment: Sorry, that's the best I can do :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez suggested in the comment, you should add a default argument:

```
import pureconfig._
import pureconfig.generic.auto._
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory

case class MyConfig(url: String, m: Map[String, String] = Map.empty)

val config1 = ConfigFactory.parseString("""{ "url": "https" }""")
val config2 = ConfigSource.fromConfig(config1).load[MyConfig]
println(config2)
```

Code run at [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/toshetah/r4J4wfEaSrCQqtYQDux3rA/4).